# element flickering on iphone when jquery.on('click') is used

Tags: jquery, html, iphone

Consider following js:

```
$('#main').on('click', '.button', function);
```

and corresponding html:

```
<div id="main">
<span class="button">button</span>
</div>
```

This works fine so far. When an element with class button is clicked, that is a child of the main element, function is called.
Unfortunately when this is viewed with an iPhone, every tap on the main element, causes it to flicker once.

I found out that this can be avoided by not binding the click event to #main, but to the entire $(document).

I haven't found anything about this issue online so far. Does someone know what is going on and if there is a nicer solution than binding every click element to the document?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Adding this to your CSS will solve the problem.